# Raycast2D end not detecting collision

Tags: godot

I have a Raycast2D where I want to detect collision with the enemy, but it does not collide at the end. What I'm saying is that it only detects collision at the place where it originates. Here is my code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

export var speed = 200
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var enemy = 0

onready var navigation_agent = $NavigationAgent2D
onready var bullet = preload("res://Bullet.tscn").instance()

func _ready():
    navigation_agent.connect("velocity_computed", self, "move")
    $RayCast2D.global_rotation = self.global_rotation - 90

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("mouse_right"):
        navigation_agent.set_target_location(event.get_global_position())

func _process(_delta):
    if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        if $RayCast2D.get_collider().is_in_group("enemy_ground_troop"):
            enemy = $RayCast2D.get_collider()
            velocity = Vector2.ZERO
            ranged_attack()

    if navigation_agent.is_navigation_finished():
        return
    
    velocity = global_position.direction_to(navigation_agent.get_next_location()) * speed

    look_at(navigation_agent.get_next_location())

    navigation_agent.set_velocity(velocity)

func move(velocity):
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func ranged_attack():
    add_child(bullet)
    bullet.global_position = self.global_position
    
    bullet.target = enemy.global_position
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

are you debugging the physics collisions during runtime?  you should be able to see if the line is intersecting or not.

look under `Debug > Visible Collision Shapes`

also try

`$RayCast2D.force_raycast_update()` inside of `_process` and see if that makes some difference.

Comment: Well, I tried the first thing and it does not stop, it goes under the enemy. The other thing does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the raycast is enabled under the inspector?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).